# facebook webhook not receiving messages via messenger

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks, facebook-webhooks

So I'm tryin to get messages via messenger webhook. It is working well locally but when I try to send a message through messenger the callback(which is Heroku) isn't happening.
I was sending the messages with an account which had no role in the app and which was also a developer account which had Admin role.
I have subscribed to messages, messaging_postbacks, message_deliveries, message_reads, message_echoes, standby events for my webhook and added my page to it. I dont necessarily think im missing anything.
...a little help Captain??

Edit: I am now obtaining messages sent by clicking test button, but not when other developer accounts sent message through messenger

Comment: First of all, how exactly did you determine that it "isn't happening"? Have you checked the log files to see whether your script on Heroku _received_ any request in the first place?

Comment: @CBroe I used `heroku logs --tail` to view live logs and I didn't receive any request there. Or is there any way for me to see if the request was sent but heroku didn't respond?

Comment: Did you _verify_ your new webhook URL correctly, when you switched from local to Heroku? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook#change_webhook

Comment: @CBroe I reverified the URL and token but as the doc says the webhook didnt verify when the URL and token where changed